# How to use one Clonezilla flash drive to automatically restore two or more different images to different computers?

Tags: usb-flash-drive, clonezilla

I have a computer enviroment with a lot of machines with two different hardware configuration, for example, 100 machines with Atom processor and 100 machines with Core i3 processor, and I want to use 10 flash drives with Clonezilla on it to restore two different images(one for Atom and one for Core i3).

I found on a [Clonezilla reference](http://clonezilla.org/related-articles//012_Automated_USB_thumb_drive_using_Custom/Automated_USB_thumb_drive_using_Custom.html) that I can automate all the user interactions of [Clonezilla restoring process](http://clonezilla.org/fine-print-live-doc.php?path=./clonezilla-live/doc/02_Restore_disk_image/00-boot-clonezilla-live-cd.doc#00-boot-clonezilla-live-cd.doc)(select image, select source and destination and all related configurations), so I want to use the same technique(automation of restore process) and use just one "kind" of flash drive image, with both restore images(Atom and Core i3) on it. I mean, I want to insert the flash drive on 200 computers(10 by 10) and let Clonezzila to choose and automatically switch from the two source images, the correct one to restore it on the target HDD by itself based on some specific hardware characteristic(such as processor type). I'm sure that there is a way but I dind't find it anywhere on my searches, can someone help me to do it?

PS: Both images have less than 3GB and everything fit on a 8GB flash drive.

Answer (score -1):

If you use the clonzilla debian live cd you can run that, and run a session for all the Atom processors, use network boot on the clients so you dont need the cd. Then once they are running do another clonezilla session and select all the Core i3 machines. You dont need to do ten at once then, you could just use multicast to do them all at once.

Comment: I cant use Clonezilla Server, I need to use Live version because the machines are on a wireless network on a client. I have also another client that have more than 2 models and I would like to use a external HDD to do that...